# How to change zoom in InteractiveViewer with bigger and smaller buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I can change the scale with `_controller!.value.scale(1 * 1.1);`

but the widget zoom starts from the top left corner. How to make it so that the increase would start from the center?

```
 InteractiveViewer(
        transformationController: _controller,
        child: Image.network(
          'https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2019-05/1556708032_1.jpg',
        ),
      ),


onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _controller!.value.scale(1 * 1.1);
              });
            }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.